# Is there any smarter way to crack wpa-2 handshake?

Tags: password-cracking

I was testing on my own router that how secure is my password. First I set a random 9 digit number as a password but the aircrack-ng was unable to crack it even in 45 minutes and tried other tools like pyrit, crunch but they also didn't work very well. So, what I was wondering is that the password cracking tools are unable to crack a mere 9 digit no. then how can they crack a strong password (combination of upper, lowercase, numbers, special characters) however it may crack the password but it can take days or even years. And the other way is phishing which doesn't work always.

How does password cracking work in the real world?

Comment: 45 minutes is not a lot of time, crunch is a password list creator (not relevant to your question)

Comment: @schroeder In real scenarios during a pentest is it okay to crack a password in hours or even in days?

Comment: It depends on the rules of engagement. You also do not explain *how* you are cracking the password. Have you seen that most tutorials use the GPU to speed up the process? Did you use GPU tools?

Comment: Yes, ocl hashcat uses the GPU but I didn't tried that because I know it would take lot of time and also because i was demonstrating myself only. And the question I am asking it in general that professionals also uses the same tools or some another tricks?

Comment: No special tools. It's a brute force situation and you use the tools to go as fast as you can go.

Comment: All the cracking tools already take into consideration using the common password list.  Most of the time spend on the bruteforce WPA password crack is actually spend on the handshake itself,  you can try your luck by splitting the attack using multiple WIfi dongle, but then you might hit the handshake limit of the WIFI Access point.

Comment: Discrete graphic cards can calculate 5 billion words per second. No professional can crack WPA2. They can only speed up dictionary attack by providing more resources but even that doesn't guarantee success.

Comment: @defalt Really? WPA2 uses 4096 PBKDF2-SHA1 rounds. Are you saying that a modern discrete GPU can calculate over 20 TH/s? A high-end GTX Titan X GPU from 2015 can only do about 5 GH/s of single SHA1...

Comment: @forest Yeah I did a mistake there. I was supposed to write 5GH/s. Can't edit it so I'll keep the comment anyway, you corrected it.

Comment: So it's all about a powerful hardware. But @mootmoot what does it mean " by splitting the attack using multiple WiFi dongle".How does it work. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPA2 is indeed a slow hash.  But in the real world, performance is better than you might suspect:

- An attacker can leverage multiple GPUs. With hashcat, six GTX 1080s can exhaust ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d in about eight minutes (and equivalent capacity  - for basic attacks - can be rented on AWS for relatively little money).
- Simple brute force and simple dictionaries are just the beginning - other techniques include using rules, masks, combinator attacks, hybrid attacks, and using larger, higher-quality dictionaries made from actual leaked passwords. These attacks are faster than brute force (often dramatically so).
- Since most passwords are human-selected and not random, analyzing the context and psychology of the target is often useful - and may be necessary to make any real progress against a non-poor (but non-random) password stored with a slow hash like WPA2.

But if that WPA2 password is truly random, and draws from all four character sets .. six 1080s would take *92 years* to fully exhaust the keyspace.

Comment: Thanks for telling the other techniques. I didn't know this before execpt a simple bruteforce.

Comment: Indeed! See https://hashcat.net/wiki/#core_attack_modes for tips on those other attacks using hashcat.

Comment: Might also want to mention just _how damn many_ clever rulesets there are!